# How to fill the text area by some data when MVC create form loading?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, code-first

I have a create form created using MVC. There is text area in that form. I want to have a pre-filled data (**Not prompt text**) to be displayed when the form loaded.This is the text area in my view.

```
  <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")), new { rows = "6", cols = "500" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message)
  </div>
```

Comment: use `TextAreaFor`, and by the way, what is happening right now? any error?

Comment: So what is your question? What problems are you having?

Comment: No, there is no error. working perfectly. When form loads initially there is no record inside the text area. That is the usual scenario right? So I want to already fill that text area with some text when loading the form instead of being it empty. Got the point??

Comment: Then set the value of your property to the value you want to display

Comment: In the GET method, set the value of `model.message = "some value";`, then in the view use `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.message)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default message, do it in the controller

```
//GET
public ActionResult Create(string default_value)
{
  MyEntity newMyEntity = new MyEntity();
  newMyEntity.message= default_value;

  return View(newMyEntity);
}
```

or if its a static text,

```
 <div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")), new { rows = "6", cols = "500", @Value = "SomeText" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message)
```

Comment: why you need to pass default to contoller?

Comment: The static way is not working. And If I user the first option how could I set the message to the text area.